# regex pattern Parse multiple strings

Tags: javascript, regex

need to filter a collection of strings based on a rather complex query I have query input as a string

```
var query =ti,su,ab(((study OR trail OR research pre/2 challeng*) n/1 (design* AND method*)) (behavior* n/1 behaviour*) OR ((behavior* or behaviour*)n/1 (change* near/6 modification*)));
```

The query can change

From this query INPUT string I want to collect just the important words:

the result that I expected = `study trail research challeng* n/1design* method* behavior* behaviour* behavior* behaviour* n/1change* modification*`

my result= `study trail research challeng* design* method*behavior* behaviour* behavior* behaviour*change* modification*`

my problem here is sometimes I got two words concatenate as an example `method*behavior*` and `behaviour*change*` and that's wrong

**DEMO:**

- This my regexp: delete words from the query: `( ti, ab, su, AND, OR, NEAR/n, P/n, pre/n n/n )`, brackets `()` and the comma `,`

> / ?[()]|\b(AND|OR|(NEAR|n|PRE|P)/\d+)(\s|$)|\b(ti|ab|su|,)\b ? /gi

```js
var query = "ti,ab,su(((study OR trail OR research pre/2 challeng*) n/1 (design* AND method*)) (behavior* n/1 behaviour*) OR ((behavior* or behaviour*)n/1 (change* near/6 modification*)))";

var subst= "";
var str = query.replace(/ ?[()]|\b(AND|OR|(NEAR|n|PRE|P)\/\d+)(\s|$)|\b(ti|ab|su|,)\b ?/gi,subst);
console.log(str)
```

every single word need to be sperate with whitespace.

I'm looking for your suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Please format your question to make it more readable

Comment: Also neither of your example variable declarations are valid javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your matched things with a space, then condense the space afterwards.

```js
var query = "ti,ab,su(((study OR trail OR research pre/2 challeng*) n/1 (design* AND method*)) (behavior* n/1 behaviour*) OR ((behavior* or behaviour*)n/1 (change* near/6 modification*)))";

var subst= " ";
var str = query.replace(/ ?[()]|\b(AND|OR|(NEAR|n|PRE|P)\/\d+)(\s|$)|\b(ti|ab|su|,)\b ?/gi,subst);
str = str.replace(/^ +|( ) +| +$/g,"$1");
console.log(str)
```

Comment: can you explain what did you do?

Comment: ... I did. Read the first sentence of the post and it literally explains the changes I made :D